# Javascript - How can I extend this script to incorporate another class change?

Tags: javascript, html, class, state

I have a piece of code that allows ajax to run once clicked.
Once the div has been clicked, not only does the ajax run, but the div changes class from 'statusOption' to 'statusOptionActive'.

It's all looking and working well so far, but I've hit a wall. I need to add in a 3rd div that also has it's class changed once clicked. You can see my new div also in the code:

My current working JavaScript for the 2 divs:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var basics = document.getElementById('basics'),
        photos = document.getElementById('photos');

    basics.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexBasics');
        var otherClasses = photos.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            basics.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            photos.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    photos.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexPhotos');        
        var otherClasses = basics.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            photos.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            basics.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        function get_query()
        {
            var url = location.href;
            var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
                qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
                result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php?user=" + get_query()['user'],true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

And here are the divs I use, where the classes change once clicked and ajax is active. The last div is the one that also needs adding to the script:

```
<div id="basics" class="statusOptionActive" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexBasics')">Basics</div>
<div id="photos" class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexPhotos')">Photos</div>
<div id="favorites" class="statusOption" onclick="loadXMLDoc('indexFav')">Message User</div>
```

////////////I've tried to get it working myself with no luck. Here's my code////////

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var basics = document.getElementById('basics'),
        photos = document.getElementById('photos'),
        messages = document.getElementById('messages');

    basics.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexBasics');
        var otherClasses = ('photos.className', 'messages.className');
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            basics.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            photos.className = 'statusOption';
            messages.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    photos.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexPhotos');        
        var otherClasses = ('basics.className', 'messages.className');
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            photos.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            basics.className = 'statusOption';
            messages.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }

    messages.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexMessages');        
        var otherClasses = ('basics.className', 'photos.className');
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            photos.className = 'statusOption';
            basics.className = 'statusOption';
            messages.className = 'statusOptionActive';
        }
    }


    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }

        function get_query(){
          var url = location.href;
          var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
          for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
            qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
            result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
          }
          return result;
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php?user=" + get_query()['user'],true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having adding the third DIV to the code? Show what you've tried and why it doesn't work?

Comment: I've added my attempt to my question for you to see where I may be going wrong

Comment: Why do you need to check the other classes before setting the new classes? Your code to check the other classes in the new version is all wrong, but it's not even needed.

Comment: It's because only one of the 3 divs can be 'active' at any time. They become highlighted you see.

Comment: Your messages button has an id "favorites" not "messages" so messages = document.getElementById('favorites'); Poking in a dark room much huh ^.^

Comment: So set the active and non-active classes without the `if()`. There's nothing wrong with setting a class that's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var otherClasses = ('basics.className', 'photos.className');
```

just sets `otherClasses` to the string `'photos.className'`, not the classes of the `basics` and `photos` DIVs. But you don't need to check the other classes at all, just set the classes that you want.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var basics = document.getElementById('basics'),
        photos = document.getElementById('photos'),
        messages = document.getElementById('messages');

    basics.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexBasics');
        basics.className = 'statusOptionActive';
        photos.className = 'statusOption';
        messages.className = 'statusOption';
    }

    photos.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexPhotos');        
        photos.className = 'statusOptionActive';
        basics.className = 'statusOption';
        messages.className = 'statusOption';
    }

    messages.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexMessages');        
        photos.className = 'statusOption';
        basics.className = 'statusOption';
        messages.className = 'statusOptionActive';
    }
```

Here's a DRY version:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var basics = document.getElementById('basics'),
        photos = document.getElementById('photos'),
        messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    var all_divs = [basics, photos, messages];

    function click_handler() {
        var id = this.id;
        var doc = 'index' + id[0].toUpperCase + id.substr(1);
        loadXMLDoc(doc);
        for (var i = 0; i < all_divs.count; i++) {
            if (all_divs[i] != this) {
                all_divs[i].className = 'statusOption';
            }
        }
        this.className = 'statusOptionActive';
    }

    basics.onclick = photos.onclick = messages.onclick = click_handler;

    ...

}
```

Comment: You sir, are some kind of genius.

Answer (score 1):

```
var basics = document.getElementById('basics'),
```

is where you get reference to your button so with provided xml

```
var button3 = document.getElementById('favorites'),
```

Then you make the class changing magic happen

```
button3.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexPhotos');        
        var otherClasses = basics.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            photos.className = 'statusOptionActive';
            basics.className = 'statusOption';
        }
    }
```

Something tells me that function is not written by you ^.^